Strategies for Analytics GitHub Activity to Enhance Team Productivity
As a manager of a growing software team, I aim to monitor our GitHub repository activity to improve team productivity and identify any development bottlenecks. My goals include:

Insights about the number of commits and pull requests per developer.
Generating weekly activity reports.
Analyzing trends over time to make informed management decisions.

I'm aware of tools that automate this process. However, I'm interested in    understanding    the best practices from a software engineering    perspective to achieve    these goals, possibly without relying    solely on third-party tools.
My Question:

What are effective strategies for monitoring and reporting on GitHub
activity to enhance team productivity?


collective performance and goal/target achivement is far better than this. i have seen people just doing monitoring rework, watch api behaviour, make api contract test, implementation usage as different task and taking 2 weeks of it which is unnessary


What are effective strategies for monitoring and reporting on GitHub activity to enhance team productivity?

Don't.
Anything based on Github activity (whether that be lines of code, pull requests or anything else) immediately favours working on quick, easy tasks over the actual hard graft which needs to be done. As soon as you make one of those a metric, you're going to decrease productivity, not increase it.

Hard lesson to learn: people only do the work you judge them on.

Measure team output instead
The challenge here is to understand why you want these metrics, and what purpose they serve. Monitoring things like commits, pull requests, the size of changesets, etc. is usually an indication that management is dissatisfied with the output of the team. I cannot project that judgement on you or your organization, but output is what you want to measure. Most other metrics can be manipulated, which give you a false sense of control and productivity.

Developers can write more verbose code to increase the number of lines written.
Developers can commit and submit smaller pull requests, thus increasing the number of PRs.

Name a metric, and it can probably be manipulated.
So, how do you measure "team output?" That's the burning question. Measuring hours of labor is problematic because overtime and changes in the size of the team change the hours logged each week. To make matters worse, it can have zero correlation with how much working software the team produces. If you replace 1 high performance senior developer with 2 beginners, they log twice as many hours together, but collectively might produce the same amount as the senior dev. Worse yet, I've seen output drop in this situation. You just can't replace experience.
Ideally, you need some sort of number that you can track over time as a correlary for team output. I know people don't like story points, but that does give you a number. Just be sure to put the team in charge of estimation, and don't barter with them. Let the points be what they are. Let the team accomplish work organically over time to see their velocity. Past output sets the bar for the next iteration.
I mentioned earlier that any metric can be manipulated, and story points are no exception. The team velocity becomes the metric used to schedule work. The team can over estimate story points. That just means velocity rises, so you schedule more work. This helps regulate any manipulation in story point values. It's not perfect, but a rise or fall in velocity has an effect on the team either way, so they tend to normalize this over time.
At the same time, track the number of production issues the team addresses. My experience has been that drops in velocity correlate to increased production issues. Naturally, you will wonder why, but don't double down on numbers. Talk to the team and get their unfiltered reasons why. Don't assume there is a "performance problem" with the humans. Remember that these people are operating in an environment where they can't control everything. Some of these uncontrolled variables are:

Aggressive deadlines from the product side of the house.
Unpredictable security issues like zero-day exploits.
New government regulations.
Team members leaving and being replaced.

Expect things to be rocky for a while, but they should normalize as time goes on.


Technical debt from years past causes work on new features to slow down.

The list can go on. The important thing is to consult the team and listen without judgement.
The reason why output drops is best answered by the team. They are the ones doing the work. The team can even be a good resource to find solutions to drops in performance. Be aware that if new feature development has been prioritized over maintenance for an extended period of time, you might have no other choice but to do some of that grinding maintenance for a while, or incorporate that maintenance into developing a new feature.
This is a tough spot to be in. I've been there, oh so many times. I've found this approach to be useful:

A number not associated with time to quantify how much new feature work the team produces.

Story points are a common measure.


A number not associated with time that allows you to quantify the maintenance and production support the team does.

I find story points for bugs to be annoying. You can't estimate a big fix. I find tracking the number of bugs worked on to be better.


Aggregate the numbers above to identify correlations, and a problem.
Consult the team on a root cause of the problem, and some options to fix it.
Work with your own management on problems identified by the team for which they have no control over.
Assume most people will pull their own weight, which helps avoid defensive responses from the team that detract from the real problem.


The worst years of my projects were after periods of highest outputs. 10x engineers worked so fast, that bugs were only fixed years after release. If you measure output at all, beware of quality and consequences. And those are next to impossible to measure.

@Basilevs, but you can come up with a number that's useful for short term planning. It won't forecast years out. And it will only work if these numbers are used as a forecast subject to change instead of a contract for work. At some point you need to have some sort of number to plan capacity and dates knowing that there is no perfect solution. "Good enough" really is good enough.

That's estimation, not measurement.

@Basilevs: the measurement is keeping track of what you complete over a period of time. You cannot measure without estimating. This is all very fuzzy and subjective, too. You just need a number that's good enough.

I tried to point out that planning requires not the measurement, but prediction. Instead of putting pressure on devs to "perform", ask them how much time this or that feature needs. There is no need for measurement however exact.

That really depends on the team. Hours. Story points. T-shirt sizes. However you hand-wave it, management needs a number so the team and make predictions. Then record what you do over time. That's your output. That's why you bring up with the team.

In my opinion you're on the wrong track. You would be better off not measuring the team's performance but instead let them themselves improve their productivity. A team of software developers is perfectly capable of measuring their performance and identify bottlenecks. Give them the responsibility and powers to take appropriate measures. Trust your team in that. As their manager it is your responsibility to organize this process.

Philip K is correct, there's no way to measure productivity here and you risk decreasing productivity with a bad metric. However there are some measures you can make.

Do Tasks/Features == Pull requests? Ideally you have one pull request per task and one task per developer per day. If you are using a pen and paper scrum board and not tracking tasks already, then you could look at PRs

Do some projects "belong" to some developers? People tend to acquire ownership of projects that they work on, and you could detect where other developers have not done any commits to a repo. Leaving the work on that repo to "the person who knows it".

Are some repos, finished/abandoned? You can check to see if work has died off on a repo.

Are some developers not doing any work at all? Check to make sure all your senior developers have been correctly assigned to interviewing new applicants and attending pre meeting meetings and aren't sneaking in any coding!!


